# Data not loading into core data database

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to put some data in the database. I'm using the following code also in other views. There does it work. But on this view it doesn't work. You can see the code below.

```
- (void)fetchKlassementIntoDocument:(UIManagedDocument *)document
{
        NSLog(@"log");
    dispatch_queue_t fetchKlassement = dispatch_queue_create("klassement fetcher", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchKlassement, ^{
        NSLog(@"Log2");
        NSLog(@"log3");
        NSArray *klassement  = [GenkData getRanking];
        [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
       NSLog(@"klassement array %@",klassement);
            for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in klassement ) {
            [Klassement klassementWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext];
                NSLog(@"inserted klassement");
            }
            NSLog(@"Log4");
            [document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
            NSLog(@"Log5");
       NSLog(@"Log 6");
         }];
    });
    NSLog(@"Log7");
    dispatch_release(fetchKlassement);
    NSLog(@"Log8");
}
```

This gives the following error log.

```
2012-10-25 10:50:07.527 RacingGenk[17989:907] log
2012-10-25 10:50:07.528 RacingGenk[17989:907] Log7
2012-10-25 10:50:07.529 RacingGenk[17989:907] Log8
2012-10-25 10:50:07.531 RacingGenk[17989:4f03] Log2
2012-10-25 10:50:07.532 RacingGenk[17989:4f03] log3
2012-10-25 10:50:07.604 RacingGenk[17989:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

After fetching the data I fill up a tableview with this data. I think that's why the error came up. But can somebody say me what is going wrong ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line from your code:

```
NSArray *klassement  = [GenkData getRanking];
```

Check the getRanking method & the klassement Array. The crash is occurring due to this line only.

Put a log for both. Hope it'll resolve your issue.

Comment: when I put this line of code in my viewDidAppear with a log. And it logs it correctly

Comment: Do one thing, add a class level NSArray Variable in Interface & allocate it in your viewDidLoad method. then assign values into it using [GenkData getRanking]; method. Also Before assigning it Put this line: NSLog(@"Found Data: %@",[GenkData getRanking]); to make sure you are getting data from method.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've tried it and the method gives back data. I Think it has something to do with the GCD.